# Remove site prefix when creating new site collection

Tags: 2010, web-application

Can I remove the site prefix from the URL when I create a new site collection? For example if the URL of the web application is `http://servername` and I want to create a new site collection I need to specify a site prefix like this `http://servername/sites/xxxx`.

Can I remove the **/sites**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called managed paths. You can create your won managed paths while creating a site collection. There can only be one site collection at the root. That is why, when you try to create more site collection you automatically get /sites in the url, while creating a site collection. However, you can click on "Define Managed Paths" and create a new managed path based on your choice.

Comment: If I want the url for example to be http://servername/intranet does that mean that there will be more than one site collection at the root?

Comment: No there can always be only one site collection at the root web application. For eample, when you create a webapplication http://servername. After that you create a site collection without including the managed path, the url to the site collection will still remain same i.e shttp://servername.But by creating a managed path "intranet"you can create as many site collections as you want (there is perhaps some upper limit, don't remember it right now) under this managed path e.g http://servername/intranet/site1, http://servername/intranet/site2 ....http://servername/intranet/siten

Comment: Ok can I hide the /sites by using alternate access mappings?